# App Engine: Having a web module and a endpoint module

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I would like to have a web and an endpoint module.

I have this working in my dev environment largely following https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-modules-sample-java .

However I can't get this working when hosted inside app engine. If I make the web module the default, I can't route to the endpoint module via dispatch.xml. This is because endpoints (apparently) need to live at /_ah/api and its not possible to route this away from the default module.

The other alternative is putting the endpoint module as the default module, however I don't then know how to route everything but /_ah/api/ to the web module. It seems that you can't route /* away from the default module.

EDIT: Note I want to have both modules running off of the same custom domain.

EDIT2: Note this is single page app. The front end module is purely html, css and js, which I want to talk to the endpoint module on the same domain.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem only resides in the routing, you can definitely have your **default module** with endpoints and a **module 'website'** for your frontend.

Then your dispatch file should look like that (python version, the Java one should be quite similar):

```
dispatch: 
- url: "*/_ah/*"
  module: default
- url: "*/*"
  module: website
```

The dispatch file apparently sets the routing with a top to bottom priority so each request targeting the endpoints */_ah/* will be routed to the default module and the rest will go on the website module.

However if you have CORS issues, you can check in the [handler configuration for static files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Including_and_excluding_files) or had the proper headers directly in your page handler code.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. My dispatch file deployment was not working. I did this manually and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the issue you have is splitting the traffic you should probably intercept all requests and look for the destination URL and divert accordingly. But i think your issue is actually accesing the endpoint deployed on a non default version.

You can deploy specific endpoints to specific (non default) versions of your app.

As stated in [the official docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#deploying_to_multiple_app_versions):

> To access backend API versions that are deployed to non-default App Engine versions of your app, you must include the version specifier in the URL, like this: https://version-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com. For example, suppose your default app version is 1, but you want to access a backend API version deployed to App Engine app version 2; you would use this URL: https://2-dot-your_app_id.appspot.com.

Comment: Thank you, however this is not ideal as it requires another DNS lookup. My goal is to have both modules running off the same custom domain.

Comment: there is no way to bridge those modules without an HTTP connection, if you point your URLs to a custom domain it will require a DNS lookup. **However** if you point all URLs in your frontend module to the "appspot url" of your backend module i understand Google will detect it's an internal IP and do the routing within its network.

Comment: To clarify further, I am writing a single page app. The front end module is purely html, css and js which talks to the endpoints module, so I do need to run it all from the one domain if I want to only have the one DNS lookup.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit on why you don't want the additional DNS lookup? Have you considered using a Managed VM with a fixed IP?

Answer (score 1):

The answer suggested by @Anhuin is good for your simpler purposes. But if you want to have totally independent modules, i suggest you to use [subdomain mapping](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain#more%5Fabout%5Fwildcard%5Fsubdomain%5Fmapping)

Create a sub domain like api.domain.com for endpoints and web.domain.com for your regular frontend modules. 
Map these in the dipatch.xml

```
<url>api.domain.com/*</url>
<module>endpointmod</module>

<url>web.domain.com/*</url>
<module>webmod</module>
```

I prefer this because '_ah' is used by appengine in multiple places like appstats, remote api and so on. This will be clearer to the people working in frontend also by calling the sub domains.